Concordance and forest plot for coxme package or multiple grouping syntax for survival package
I am trying to run staggered entry survival models where individuals have differential monitoring time so I am trying to group by individual id in the model, and individuals are part of a larger group (multiple individuals within a bird's nest) where group needs to be considered as a random effect. Below is sample code:
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(coxme)


#Creating dataframe
individualid <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,6)
groupid <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
event <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
entry <- c(0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,1,2)
exit <- entry + 1
precip <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, .2, 1, 0, 0.2, 0,0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0)
temp <- c(50, 70, 50, 70, 62, 50, 70, 62, 44, 81, 92, 66, 32, 32, 32, 51, 42)

data <- data.frame(individualid, groupid, event, entry, exit, precip, temp)

#univariate model
model1 <- coxph(Surv(entry, exit, event) ~ temp,
      data = data)

#model with random intercept term
model2 <- coxph(Surv(entry, exit, event) ~ temp +
        frailty(groupid),
      data = data)

#model with individual grouping
model3 <- coxph(Surv(entry, exit, event) ~ temp, 
        cluster = data$individualid,
      data = data)

#model with random intercept term and indivdiual grouping
model4 <- coxph(Surv(entry, exit, event) ~ temp + frailty(groupid), 
      cluster = data$individualid,
      data = data)

#this runs with sample data, but not with my real data. The suvival vignette also explicitly states
#that a frailty term cannot be used in the same model with a cluster term

#model5 <- coxph(Surv(entry, exit, event) ~ temp + frailty(groupid) + frailty(individualid),
              #  data = data)
#This crashes R when run with sample data. For my real data, I get the following message:
#Error in coxpenal.fit(X, Y, istrat, offset, init = init, control, weights = weights,  : 
                        #Only one sparse penalty term allowed

concordance(model1)
#works

survminer::ggforest(model1, data = as.data.frame(data))
#works



#mixed effect model with fixed and random effects to distinguish group and individual
model6 <- coxme(Surv(entry, exit, event) ~ temp + (1|groupid) + (1|individualid), 
                data = data)

model6$concordance
#null

survminer::ggforest(model6, data = as.data.frame(data))
#error


I could not find a way to include multiple grouping terms in the 'survival' package, so I moved on to the 'coxme' package which allows grouping by individualid and groupid, but I cannot find a method within this package to calculate concordance or create forest plots for visuals. I am okay with using either package, but I need either A) a method to consider multiple groupings in 'survival' or B) a method to calculate concordance and create plots in 'coxme'

I'm not knowledgeable on Cox modeling, but survival::concordance allows for formulas....Is this what you're looking for? (using the formula in model6)  concordance(Surv(entry, exit, event) ~ temp + (1|groupid) + (1|individualid), data = data)

I get this error when doing that:
Error in concordance.formula(Surv(entry, exit, event) ~ temp +  :
No (non-missing) observations
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(1, groupid) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors                                                       It does allow me to use this formula without the random effects, but I would like to keep the random effects in the model and get a measure of the model fit still

Do you get that error with your real data or the data in your question? If the data in your question, try to update the survival package. Let me know, either way.

I get it with my real data

Is the data structure different? Look at the typeof and class as it compares to the data in this question. If that's not the issue, then look for incomplete data (NA? NULL?)
